# Tools are locating Unknown code in robots.txt

Tags: html, robots.txt, google-search-console

Recently I uploaded a robots.txt in root directory of my website.
The things which I wrote in robots.txt file are-

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /download/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: */feed/
Sitemap: http://stockfirmware.me/sitemap.xml
```

But all the robots.txt analyzers including Google WMTools and Yandex are showing wrong codes there.

The things which all tools show are--

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /download/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: */feed/
Sitemap: http://stockfirmware.me/sitemap.xml
//*

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

I don't know from where the last 3-4 lines came and I dont know their location too.
I needed Help regarding this. Please Help me. Thanks

Comment: Do you see this also when opening your robots.txt? Assuming it’s [this one](http://stockfirmware.me/robots.txt), I don’t see it.  -- Do you use hosting24.com as web hoster?

Comment: I can't see that on http://stockfirmware.me/robots.txt  But  When I check it with various robots.txt checker tools , that code appeard there.

Comment: Well Its fault of the webhosting company .I found a solution of this. Thanks

Comment: Would you post an answer about the solution (and accept it to mark the question as solved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because `hosting24.com` is appending this code to all outgoing files from their server. You should tell them it's a bug and they should not do it for `robots.txt`.